# Subscribing multiple actors to Dead Letters in Akka

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka

I am trying to create a simple application that has two actors:

- Master actor that handles some App actions
- DeadLettersListener that is supposed to handle all dead or unhandled messages

Here is the code that works perfectly:

```
object Hw extends App {
  // creating Master actor
  val masterActorSystem = ActorSystem("Master")
  val master = masterActorSystem.actorOf(Props[Master], "Master")

  // creating Dead Letters listener actor
  val deadLettersActorSystem = ActorSystem.create("DeadLettersListener")
  val listener = deadLettersActorSystem.actorOf(Props[DeadLettersListener])

  // subscribe listener to Master's DeadLetters
  masterActorSystem.eventStream.subscribe(listener, classOf[DeadLetter])
  masterActorSystem.eventStream.subscribe(listener, classOf[UnhandledMessage])
}
```

According to the akka manual though, ActorSystem is a heavy object and we should create only one per application. But when I replace these lines:

```
val deadLettersActorSystem = ActorSystem.create("DeadLettersListener")
val listener = deadLettersActorSystem.actorOf(Props[DeadLettersListener])
```

with this code:

```
val listener = masterActorSystem.actorOf(Props[DeadLettersListener], "DeadLettersListener")
```

The subscription does not work any more and DeadLettersListener is not getting any Dead or Unhandled messages.

Can you please explain what am I doing wrong and give an advice how to subscribe to Dead Letters in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really imagine what are you doing wrong, I created a small example, and it seems to work:

```
object Hw extends App {

  class Master extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case a => println(s"$a received in $self")
    }
  }

  class DeadLettersListener extends Actor {
    override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
      case a => println(s"$a received in $self")
    }
  }

  // creating Master actor
  val masterActorSystem = ActorSystem("Master")
  val master = masterActorSystem.actorOf(Props[Master], "Master")
  val listener = masterActorSystem.actorOf(Props[DeadLettersListener])

  // subscribe listener to Master's DeadLetters
  masterActorSystem.eventStream.subscribe(listener, classOf[DeadLetter])
  masterActorSystem.eventStream.subscribe(listener, classOf[UnhandledMessage])

  masterActorSystem.actorSelection("/unexistingActor") ! "yo"
}
```

Could you try it?

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me to narrow down and identify the problem which was that I had other code that eventually did 

`masterActorSystem.shutdown()`

I assumed that this would kill Master actor, but apparently it was killing all stream actors including DeadLettersListener.